# Plot a function during debugging in Python

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib

I used to work in Matlab and it is really convenient (when working with big arrays/matrices and nested functions) to visualize intermediate results during debugging using `plot` function.

In Python I cannot plot anything in debug mode: a window with figure plot is never loaded (I am using Spyder IDE for coding and `matplotlib.pyplot` for plotting).

This is really annoying when debugging nested function and classes. 
Does anyone know a good solution? Of course, I can always output intermediate results, however it is not convenient.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: Do you know Jupyter notebook: https://jupyter.org/?

Comment: I don't know any solution. But I want to mention that I never ever used Debugging mode even when debugging. Instead, `print` statements are completely fine to find out the current state of a script.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I did use Jupyter notebook, but I'd prefer spyder. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how do you use print statements? In command line during debug mode? When working with big (say, N=1000) vectors, visualization is more convenient

Comment: What I mean is that when not in Debugging mode, you can easily plot whatever you like at any point in the script, just as you'd do with print statements.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but how do I execute my script up to a certain point without a debugger?

Comment: If you call `plt.show()` the script stops automatically until you close the figure. You can also trigger any error, which lets the script stop, like `assert False`.

Comment: That is a good alternative. Thanks. It answers my quesiton

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to show the plot without breaking the debugging process.

All you need to do is to issue `plt.pause(1)` command, which will display the plots, and then one can continue the debugging process.

Comment: I am curios about how you found this?

Comment: @Angelos by try and error

Comment: Clunky as hell, but it probably doesn't get any better! Working on Windows probably requires working with Windows-native tooling, not this good old Linux stuff that needs to be ported.

Comment: it doesnt work (i am debugging directly from vscode not the terminal)