# How to plot during debugger-mode of VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visualization

How to plot using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) in **debugging** mode. Using the below code in the debugging console only gives me the object adress, but not the output. Same true for e.g. plt.plot(a).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.random.randn(64,64)*20+100
plt.imshow(a)
>> <matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x000002CFEEC37F28>
```

If I try the same code in VSCode-python interactive-shell (using the jupyter service)

I get this as expected

[image]

Later my goal is to be able to call any visualization library during debugging mode (e.g. a wrapped-in java-library), because it allows me to live-check how my processed data is doing.

Comment: What happens if you define your own helper method and call it that way? My suspicion is the way the debugging console works is interfering with the underlying's call to launch the plot because it's pulling it directly out of Python versus letting Python itself run things.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I tried it with our own visualization library using javabridge-package and calling external java-visualization interface and it worked like a charm. Somehow now trying: plt.imshow(my_image); plt.show() now worked and I can access plotting functions inside of debugging environment of VSCode. Nice. Thanks for the suggestion as well. :)

Comment: what version of plt are you using, plt.imshow(my_image); plt.show() does not show anything for me...

Answer (score 10):

Using `plt.show()` or `plt.pause(1)` will open the plot in a new window.

However in my case, where I am debugging via VS Code Remote Development Extension Pack (e.g. SSH, WSL, Docker, etc), I have to rely on VS Code Jupyter Interactive Window to render matplotlib figures.

#### Solution

At the entry script of your solution code base (e.g. `main.py`), either start a debugging session in Interactive Window (`> Jupyter: Debug Current File in Interactive Window`) from the command palette, or, as I prefer, add `#%%` at the first line and click `Debug Cell`.

[image]

You can now interactively render your plots during a VS Code debugging session (**via the Debug Console NOT INTERACTIVE WINDOW**), regardless of whether it is locally or remotely

[image]

There is a discussion about this on GitHub

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1278

Comment: I've exactly the same issue (debugging from ssh). However, when i am trying to use the `> Jupyter: Debug Current File in Interactive Window`the debugger does not work, it stays always in the first line in ìmport numpy as np' with the circle with two arrows moving without finishing.

AS i could not find a solution i open a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959034/show-matplotlib-figures-during-debug-in-visual-studio-code-using-ssh-conection)

Comment: @VictorCB `circle with two arrows moving without finishing`. This seems like the loading icon for the Interactive Window. Indeed, Jupyter will wait for the current cell to finish before you can run the next cell. If you have a breakpoint somewhere, it will be waiting until you continue. Have you tried using the Python debug console instead?

Comment: @VictorCB If you look at the image in my answer, I am debugging and rendering plots using the Jupyter Interactive Windows, but I am also using the Python Debug Console for interacting with the breakpoint on a separate thread. Jupyter Interactive Window and Python Debug Console are separate windows in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks! now i got it and it works! I was trying to interact with the Jupiter interactive window rather than the Python Debug Console.

Comment: @fabda01 I can't display the output of the debugging console on the jupyter interactive window. Aren't those two separate debugging sessions? So to make it clear, do you start the jupyter debugging and then the debugging via the console?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506354/plot-a-function-during-debugging-in-python) that if you use plt.pause(1), the plot will show up

Answer (score 0):

Install "debug visualizer" extension in VScode. It is very fast and convenient to use. You can find more info on the extension page! Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I found out that you can just add

`plt.show(plt.imshow(a))`

Comment: Hiho, thanks for the answer, but I already answered by myself on the 29th of July (comment). But how can I mark this as the sufficient answer? Do I have to answer to my own post again?

Comment: Ah I didn't check the comment. No it's okay to mark again. Thank you :)

Comment: get me this error ib/pyplot.py", line 353, in show
    return _backend_mod.show(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given